# convert R matrix to text2vec dtm

Tags: r, text-mining, text2vec

I have a R matrix `mat` and I want to perform LDA on it.

When I run `lda_model$fit_transform(mat, n_iter = 20)`, I get an error:

```
Error in super$check_convert_input(x) : 
 don't know how to deal with input of class 'matrix'
```

Is there an easy way to solve this? The source for my matrix is not text and I don't want to go into vocabularies, `itoken()`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Casting to `sparseMatrix` before fitting the model seems to do the trick:

```
library(Matrix)
mat <- as(mat, "sparseMatrix")
```